# Exec not finding var when running as sudo -H -u user

Tags: bash

I have a script to check if a script is already running or not. When executing it as `./script.sh` it works fine, but when executing it as `sudo -H -u www-data ./script.sh` I get the following error: `./script.sh: 6: exec: 99: not found`.

The path is correct and I also gave full permissions to the lockfile.

To avoid the script running concurrently I want to use a lock file. The script will be called by a cron job but can also be executed by a web server through user input.

```
LOCK_FILE="/my/path/test.lock"
exec 99>"$LOCK_FILE"

flock -n 99
RC=$?
if [ "$RC" != 0 ]; then
echo "locked"
  exit 1
else
echo "unlocked"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) in your script to make sure to run **bash** instead of the default **sh**. As on some systems */bin/sh* is a symbolic link to some other shells like **dash** for example. And the latter does have its own version of *exec* command:

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 oct.   25  2019 /bin/sh -> dash
$ dash
$ exec 99>/tmp/foo
dash: 1: exec: 99: not found
```

But with *bash*, it works:

```
$ bash
$ exec 99>/tmp/foo
$ ls -l /tmp/foo 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 xxxx xxxx 0 nov.   16 10:10 /tmp/foo
```

So, add the *shebang* in the first line of your script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

LOCK_FILE="/my/path/test.lock"
exec 99>"$LOCK_FILE"

flock -n 99
RC=$?
if [ "$RC" != 0 ]; then
echo "locked"
  exit 1
else
echo "unlocked"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually did have the shebang in my script. I think the problem was that I accidentally had a empty line above the shebang that I didn't notice. After remove the empty line the script is working even when executing it as a different user.